# How do I locate the Financial Type ID?

Tags: civicontribute, import, financial-types

I am trying to import hundreds of contribution records and it is requiring I include the Financial Type ID when importing. Simply having the word Donation is not enough! When I visit Administer - CiviContribute - Financial Types, it does not display the Financial Type ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When importing contributions, you must specify the Financial Type in the form of the Financial Type ID.  Unfortunately going to Administer - CiviContribute - Financial Types does not display the Financial Type ID.  You must get the Financial Type ID from the API Explorer

Go to Support - Developer - then one of the following:

**API Explorer V3**

- Entity: Financial Type
- Action: getlist
- Parameters: Leave blank
- Execute

You will revive a list of all the Financial Type labels and their ID numbers.

For example:

```
  "id": "7",
        "label": "Money Donations",
        "description": [
            "For all monetary donations.  "
```

In this case **7** is the Financial Type ID for **Money Donations**

**API Explorer V4**

- Good luck and
- don't !@#$ it up.

So pretty much use V3 as v4 does not use getlist. ;)

Comment: You should use get over getlist... Because not all entity is configured to use getlist

Comment: Want to let us know how you would get the financial type ID via the API V4?

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to do this via the UI I believe this is as simple as going to civicrm/admin/financial/financialType?reset=1 and mousing over or clicking on Edit for each Financial Type and the ID will show in the url

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for this, you can use the getFields action on the Contribution entity to locate the options for the Financial Type ID.

```
$fields = \Civi\Api4\Contribution::getFields()
  ->setLoadOptions([
    'id', 
    'name', 
    'label', 
    'abbr', 
    'description', 
    'color', 
    'icon',
  ])
  ->addWhere('options', '!=', FALSE)
  ->addWhere('name', '=', 'financial_type_id')
  ->execute();
```